# Web App for smartphones in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, smartphone

I have been looking around recently to try and find a good place to learn how to start making my website more smartphone friendly when it is visited by an iPhone, android, or blackberry. This is something like what Digg.com does when it is visited by a smartphone. I have found a few tutorials for PHP but none for ASPX, and all I have is windows servers.

Could anyone point me in the right direction, and show me were to find a quick run through on how to do something like this? I am a bit lost. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP on Windows Based web servers. Here are some quick links for ASP.Net for mobile.

[Web for mobile devices - best practices for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396280/web-for-mobile-devices-best-practices-for-asp-net)
http://www.w3schools.com/dotnetmobile/default.asp
http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial120_Introduction-to-ASP.NET-Mobile.html
http://www.devasp.net/net/search/display/category310.html
http://www.asp.net/mobile/