# How to develop Windows Mobile 6.5 apps

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm new to Windows Mobile 6.5 app development. Which language do I need to learn and which books are preferable? Can you direct me to eBook sites for Windows Mobile apps development?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Mobile Development - Where to begin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377604/windows-mobile-development-where-to-begin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a choice between C++, C#, or Visual Basic since Windows Mobile supports [multiple languages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677133.aspx). You will likely need to use Visual Studio for easiest end-to-end development (you can get [express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/) for free). I don't know of any good books to recommend, but you can use Microsoft's official tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb250560.aspx).

Finally, you can find the SDK [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=20686a1d-97a8-4f80-bc6a-ae010e085a6e).