# How to Develop Applications for windows mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile

Hi i want to know how to develop applications for Windows Mobiles. Which Sdk i need to install, and what are the steps i need to fallow?
can any suggest me?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Shiva.M

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490779.aspx

Comment: Which edition are you interested in? There are massive differences between 6 & 7.

Comment: Windows Phone 7 is not branded Windows Mobile - those are two very different environments, with very little cross-compatibility. In terms of market share, WinMo currently has ~9% and WinPhone7 has ~1% (http://blog.nielsen.com/nielsenwire/online_mobile/in-us-smartphones-now-majority-of-new-cellphone-purchases/).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Mobile 6.5, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985/getting-started-with-windows-mobile-development).

For Windows Phone 7, take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402466/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7).